# How to use speech recognition results to filter/search element

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

I'm trying to make a read out website, with a long text that we can only read out, without any possible scrolling. But I'm not really good with pure JS and I'm a little bit lost. I tried speech recognition and in a second time to make a filter/search list.

In an other side, I'm taking each words of a `<p>` to separate them in `<spans>`, because I suppose I have to make something like "When you 
hear `<span>1</span>`, you wait to hear `<span>2</span>`" and so on...
But for the moment, I'm making a list and not span, like that :

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Say something..." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Hello world</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bye world</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">See you world</a></li>
</ul>
```

And JS :

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in a second time I tried to merge it with a speechRecognition input, without success :

```
<form>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="start" />
</form>
<div id="interimResult"></div>
<div id="finalResult">Let speak</div>
```

I did a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fromager/b9absjaq/) where I separate the two function now because I didn't find anything...

But, Am I going in the good way... I have to manage long text and `<li>` are not good, when I'll make it with `<span>` or anything else, will it be the same method ?

Answer (score 0):

You add a call to `myFunction` inside `recognition.onresult`, you also modify `myFunction` to accept recognized text as an argument, it will do the job:

```
function myFunction(filter) { // HERE WE TAKE FILTER AS AN ARGUMENT
  var ul, li, a, i;
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}


recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var interimTranscript = "";
  for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
    var _transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
    if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
      finalTranscript = StringUtils.capitalize(_transcript);
      myFunction(finalTranscript); // <-- HERE IT FILTERS 
                                   // USING SPEECH RECOGNITION RESULT
    }
```

It is better to give your function `myFunction` more meaningful name though, for example `filterView` is much better name.